# Disable UISegmentedControl based on condition of another UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two UISegmentedControl, one of which I want to use to enable / disable the other. I have written a function to handle this as follows:

```
   - (void)disableSegment2 {
    if ([_segment1 isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:0] && [_segment1 isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:2]) {
        _segment2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    } else if ([_segment1 isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:1]) {
        _segment2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }
}
```

When I call this function from viewDidLoad _segment2 remains disabled regardless of the condition of _segment1. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't get your question. BTW Use || in place of &&

Comment: You have one segment control with 2 buttons or 2 segmented control clarify this

Comment: Two segmented control. One with three buttons, the other with two. When two of the three buttons on the first segmented control are selected the second segmented control should be disabled, otherwise the second control should be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the condition to this-

```
  - (void)disableSegment2 {
        if ([_segment1 isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:0] && [_segment1 isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:2]) {
            _segment2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
 else if (![_segment1 isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:0] || ![_segment1 isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:2]) {
            _segment2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
```

I think it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IBAction with your 1st controller, test whether >= 2 segmenets are selected, disable 2nd segmented control.

The way you have it set up now, this `disableSegment2` is only being called *once*, when the view loads. You need to call it each time your first segment control is updated.